# UICollectionViewCell clicks will not register correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` with some cells.

I have a weird bug where clicking on a cell registers sometimes as a click on wrong cell.

The behavior:

If I have Cell A and Cell B, and I clicked cell A and then cell B, the click on cell B registers as a click on cell A. Another click on Cell B then registers properly on B.

According to this, first click on ANY cell once a view loads is ignored.
If I click on cell A twice after clicking on cell B before, it ends up being cell B was clicked once and cell A was clicked once.

Another way to look at it:

Whenever I click on a cell while the previous click was on a DIFFERENT cell, the new click registers on the previous cell.

Another way to look at it:

Each click is registered on the previously clicked cell.

I'm confused by this. Any help please ?

My class:

```
class SelectCells: ProductsTableViewController
{

    var m_productsToPurchaseList : [String : Double] = [:]
    var m_sellerID = ""

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.LoadProductsByUserID(productsToShow: Constants.Products.ProductTrees.MY_SALES, UserID: m_sellerID) // My sales is all sales in contact perspective

    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        // Display selected Item

        print(indexPath.item)
        print(indexPath.section)

        let prodForPurchase = products[indexPath.row]
        let prodForPurchaseID = prodForPurchase.getUniqueID()

        prodForPurchase.toggleProductSelected()

        if (prodForPurchase.isProductMarked())
        {
            // Product not yet marked for purchase. Need to add it for purchase
            m_productsToPurchaseList[prodForPurchaseID] = prodForPurchasePrice
        }
        else
        {
            // Product already marked for purchase. Need to remove it from purchase
            m_productsToPurchaseList.removeValue(forKey: prodForPurchaseID)
        }

        ProductsCollection.reloadData()

    }        
}
```

Functions from super class:

```
extension ProductsCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource
{

    func createCollectionViewCell(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "product_collection_cell", for: indexPath) as! ProductsCollectionViewCell
        cell.ProductImageView.image = nil
        cell.ProductName.text = nil
        cell.ProductPrice.text = nil
        cell.productUniqueID = nil

        let prodInCell =  searchActive ? filtered[indexPath.row] : products[indexPath.row]

        let prodID = prodInCell.getUniqueID()
        cell.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        if let str = prodInCell.urlStr
        {
            cell.ProductImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:str), placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DefaultProductImage"))
        }
        else
        {
            let dbRef = Storage.storage().reference().child(prodID).child("pic0.jpg")
            cell.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            cell.ProductImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DefaultProductImage")
            dbRef.downloadURL(completion:
                {
                    url, error in
                    if let error = error
                    {
                        Constants.logger.error(error)
                    }
                    else if let url = url
                    {
                        prodInCell.setUrlStr(str: url.absoluteString)  // store for upcoming need
                        cell.ProductImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:url.absoluteString), placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DefaultProductImage"))
                        cell.ProductImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleToFill
                        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
                    }
            })

        }
        cell.ProductImageView.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.ProductName.text = prodInCell.getName()
        cell.ProductPrice.text = String(prodInCell.getPrice())
        cell.productUniqueID = prodInCell.getUniqueID()

        let isProductMarked : Bool = prodInCell.isProductMarked()

        cell.backgroundColor = isProductMarked ? UIColor.green : UIColor.clear
        cell.layer.borderColor = isProductMarked ? UIColor.yellow.cgColor : UIColor.black.cgColor

        return cell
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        return createCollectionViewCell(collectionView, cellForItemAt: indexPath)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        // Display selected Item
        prodToLoad = products[indexPath.row]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "view_product_information", sender:self  )
    }



    // Swift 3.0
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        return GetViewCGSize(collectionView)
    }

// This function was created so that we can override it for different views that are ProductsCollectionView to have cells look different
    func GetViewCGSize(_ collectionView: UICollectionView) -> CGSize
    {
        return CGSize(width: CGFloat((collectionView.frame.size.width / 3) - 20), height: CGFloat(100))
        }
   }
```

Comment: First of all, can you just write print(indexPath.item) and print(indexPath.section) at the beginning of the method and confirm those are wrong?

Comment: It seems indexPath.item is always the same, "0", but section seems OK. It changes according to the cell I click

Comment: How many sections and how many items in each section you must have?

Comment: The issue is happening because of `ProductsCollection.reloadData()` call in the didSelect. Either you reload only the selected cell or manipulate the cell from didSelect itself

Comment: Can you suggest a solution please @MidhunMP

Comment: I deleted the "Reload", @MidhunMP . It did not solve the problem

Comment: @Ofri: Is your table view have multi-selection enabled ? Or did you implement `didDeselect` method? If possible, could you please share a sample project which have the same issue ? From your code, everything seems fine. May be the issue is related to your view configuration or touch handling etc

Comment: I do not have didSelect method... is it the same as didSelectAt ? I already have it written in the question :)

Comment: Also, I Do not know about multi selection..

Comment: @Ofri Can you share all of your codes for this class here? then only I hope we can help you.

Comment: Added @PranavanSp :)

Comment: Please see new code added @PranavanSp

Comment: In **didSelectItemAt** switch case for the different cells. @Ofri

Comment: I do not understand your suggestion.Can you please write an example? @JhonnyTawk

Comment: switch indexPath.item {
        case 0:
            // This is for cell1
        case 1:
            // This is for cell2
        default:
                print("")
        }

Comment: didSelectItemAt method doesn't seem relevant here. It has uses in other sections in the code. How will that help?

Comment: Awaiting your reply @JhonnyTawk

Comment: @Ofri its complicated from your code. ProductsCollection is not defined as above code. give a code on `ProductsCollectionViewController` and `ProductsTableViewController`. conflict with table view and collection view

Comment: Can you remove the code block under the comment `Swift 3`. Namely the `sizeForItemAt indexPath ` function? This is not a solution but I have a hunch I need to test out.

Comment: Hey @jms, Commenting that function out did nothing

Comment: Most probably there is something wrong with numberOfItemsInSection and numberOfSections methods in your implementation.. Though you didn't share them in the code snippet @Ofri

Comment: I do not even override them. They are the default implementation @MostafaAbdellateef

Comment: Sorry, I AM overriding numberOfItemsInSection, but if search is active it returns the number of unfiltered items, and when not active just products.count. This is not what causes this bug

Comment: is this issue happening after search or before ? seems like numberOfItems may be a problem. try putting ProductCollectionView.reloadData() into a DispatchQueue.main.async block once you have your model updated

Comment: Just post code and I will fix it. It takes much more time to fix issue without compilable code. Issue can be related to CV layout, business logic, etc.

Answer (score 2):

From a quick read on your code, you don't store anywhere the prodForPurchase state on the controller and then you reload the data.

Check after the reload that the items are having the desired state.

Also, try to remove the code from the cellForItem and implement it on the cell class.

Comment: Hey, I don't exactly understand. Can you please give me a code example ?

Comment: Still waiting for your clarification @Kalaitzidis

Comment: I think I did what you said to, it did not solve the problem.\

Comment: you have gotten the auto-bounty award, the least you can do is see this through and reply.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted implementation of `isProductMarked()` func. It looks like its value is not updated. Don't forget to update product marked flag on tap.

Comment: IsProductMarked simply returns a bool... Starts off as "false", and changes when using "toggle" function